# how to make side by side Divs (with <p> inside) as a 2-column table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a side-by-side table with 2 divs column, that contains many `<p>` elements inside.
That would be easy if these two Divs and their contents are horizontal, but in this case, they are vertical, two sides' heights are not the same.

Is there any way to do it without using JavaScript?

*EDIT:
The reason I put two separate divs side by side is that I put new content to them using JavaScript Prepend.
On the left side are the English texts, and on the right side are translated texts.
It would be easier for me if the English texts were together inside a div and the same for the translated texts.

I have done it by using Javascript and setting one side's style. height = the other side's clientHeight, it would be much better if I was able to do this with only CSS and HTML

```js
for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#div1 p').length; i++) {
  
document.querySelectorAll('#div1 p')[i].style.height = "auto";
document.querySelectorAll('#div2 p')[i].style.height = "auto";



if (document.querySelectorAll('#div1 p')[i].clientHeight > document.querySelectorAll('#div2 p')[i].clientHeight )
{
 document.querySelectorAll('#div2 p')[i].style.height = document.querySelectorAll('#div1 p')[i].clientHeight-3+'px'
}
else 
{
 document.querySelectorAll('#div1 p')[i].style.height = document.querySelectorAll('#div2 p')[i].clientHeight-3+'px'
}
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Consolas,Menlo,"courier new",monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.grid-container {}

#div1{
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}

#div2{
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
}

p{
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #0000ff00;
  border-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="div2" class="skiptranslate"> 
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley.</p>
    <p> the second cell</p>
    <p> the 3rd cell </p>
    <p> the 4th cell </p>
  </div>
  <div id="div1" >
    <p> I want this cell's height same as the left "lorem ipsum" cell </p>
    <p> the second cell</p>
    <p> the 3rd cell</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to have rows that takes the whole width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here how i would do it, with rows taking 100% and cells taking 50%

```css
.cell {
  width: 50%
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #0000ff00;
  border-color: gray;
}

body {
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, "courier new", monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class=" grid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <p> I want this cell's height same as the left "lorem ipsum" cell </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <p> the second cell</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <p> the second cell</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <p> the 3rd cell </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <p> the 3rd cell </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <p> the 4th cell </p>
    </div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, Thank you LK77 and Rhyan-WoodsAndWalker, for helping. The reason I put two separate divs side by side is that I put new content to them using JavaScript Prepend. On the left side are the English texts, and on the right side are translated texts.
It would be easier for me if the English texts are together inside a div and the same for the translated texts. I have done it by using Javascript and setting one side's style.height = the other side's clientHeight

Comment: Well it's easier to do it that way, since you create a row, and put the english text and the translation in it at once, having two separate columns make it harder both for css and js

Answer (score 1):

just to add to LK77s good answer - is there any reason why you can't just use a `<table>` element here? That's the simplest solution.

failing that, a more modern solution is to refactor the HTML to take out the column `div`s, then you could use `display: flex` or `display: grid` to accomplish this:

```css
.flex-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.flex-table p {
  margin: 0;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50;
 }

.grid-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid-table p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
 }


/**
Just to show the different columns
**/
.table p:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-table table">
  <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum second cell</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum third cell</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum fourth cell</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum fifth cell</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum sixth cell</p>
</div>
  
  
  <div style="margin-bottom: 30px"></div>
  
<div class="grid-table table">
  <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum second cell</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum third cell</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum fourth cell</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum fifth cell</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum sixth cell</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for giving me many ways, I have edited the reason and solution. Hope someone else needs it.